# discord.js how to return all members from a current role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i am currently working on some updates for my discord bot, I am using discord.js 
and trying to get all the usersnames from a current role via dm, 
For example, if 3 users have the role Admin, 
then the 3 usernames will be returned via message, 
so far i have this

```
    bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel)
    {
    if(msg.content == prefix + "des"){            
        let RoleName = "Admin";
        let guildid = "idwashere";
        let memberWithRole = 
    bot.guilds.get(guildid).roles.get("name", 
    RoleName).members;

        console.log(memberWithRole);
        msg.reply("Feature coming soon");
    }
}
});
```

i get a error

```
let memberWithRole = 
bot.guilds.get(guildid).roles.get("name", 
RoleName).members;
                                                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of 
undefined
```

i feel i'm close but yet not sure what im doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it 
i changed memberswithrole to

```
        let memberWithRole = bot.guilds.get(guildid).roles.find("name", RoleName).members.map(m=>m.user.username);
```

this then returns the username 
If anyone has any better way or imrpovents please let me know.

Comment: in version 12 ```find("name", RoleName)``` will not work

You need to use ```someCollection.find(element => element.property === value);```